# Dynamically Populating a Field with $addFields When Getting Document By Id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to use `$aggregate` and the `$addFields` to dynamically populate a field when I run a getById() function in my MongoDB collection. Basically what I want to do is pull out the last element in an array of objects from a property called "history", and dynamically populate that to a field titled "activeStatus", which is an object. So this particular block of code looks like this:

```
await db.collection("staffmembers").aggregate([{ $addFields: { activeStatus: { $arrayElemAt: ["$history", -1.0] } } }, { $out: "staffmembers" }]);
```

This is what the full getById() function looks like:

```
exports.getById = async function(req, res) {
  let doc;
  let MongoClient = await require("../config/database")();
  let db = MongoClient.connection.db;

  let request = new EndpointRequestController(
    req,
    res,
    // Allowed Parameters
    {
      id: {
        type: String
      }
    },
    [
      // Required Parameters
      "id"
    ]
  );

  await db.collection("staffmembers").aggregate([{ $addFields: { activeStatus: { $arrayElemAt: ["$history", -1.0] } } }, { $out: "staffmembers" }]);

  try {
    doc = await StaffMember.findOne(
      {
        _id: request.parameters.id
      },
      {}
    ).exec();
    if (doc) req.documentCount = 1;
  } catch (err) {
    return request.sendError("An error occurred while trying to find existing records.", err);
  }

  res.send(doc);
};
```

While I don't get any errors, I don't see "activeStatus" in the resulting document.

Is this something I can do in a situation like this? And, if so, what a I missing?

By the way, my document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": <id value>,
    "type": "permanent",
    "gender": "female",
    "history": [
        {
            "endDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.721Z",
            "stage": "training",
            "completed": true,
            "startDate": "2018-10-30T13:41:18.714Z"
        },
        {
            "stage": "active",
            "completed": false,
            "startDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.572Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the doc I want to produce:

```
{
    "_id": <id value>,
    "type": "permanent",
    "gender": "female",
    "history": [
        {
            "endDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.721Z",
            "stage": "training",
            "completed": true,
            "startDate": "2018-10-30T13:41:18.714Z"
        },
        {
            "stage": "employed",
            "completed": false,
            "startDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.572Z"
        }
    ],
    "activeStatus": {
            "stage": "employed",
            "completed": false,
            "startDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.572Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that await is missing in front of `aggregate`, could you try that ?

Comment: I added the "await" in front of the aggregate block, still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`await db.collection("staffmembers").aggregate([{ $addFields: { activeStatus: { $arrayElemAt: ["$history", -1.0] } } }, { $out: "staffmembers" }])`

returns type [AggregationCursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/AggregationCursor.html) since you're using raw node.js MongoDB driver. So actually there's no database call executed.

You have two ways to fix that:

1) Use mongoose API:

```
await StaffMember.aggregate([{ $addFields: { activeStatus: { $arrayElemAt: ["$history", -1.0] } } }, { $out: "staffmembers" }]);
```

2) "Force" the cursor to execute the query (using `next()` or `toArray()`)

```
let cursor = db.collection('staffmembers').aggregate([{ $addFields: { activeStatus: { $arrayElemAt: ["$history", -1.0] } } }, { $out: "staffmembers" }]);
await cursor.toArray()
```